# 8 IQ test questions - colored boxes, shapes, lines

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

I recently took an IQ test with 50 questions of visual standard, 42 of which I got right. However, these are the 8 that I was unable to resolve. What do these pictures have in common?

The source is the book ["Improve Your IQ: Over 500 Mind-Bending Puzzles"](https://www.amazon.com.br/Improve-Your-IQ-Mind-bending-Puzzles/dp/0760716838)

Author: Deborah Hercun
Publisher: Marco Zero
[image]

Comment: Posting a large portion of a puzzle collection seems to be skirting dangerously close to copyright infringement. Posting one puzzle, with attribution, could be argued to be permissible under "fair use" or "doesn't constitute a 'work'" clauses in most copyright laws. A collection of 8 puzzles, I'm not so sure. IANAL, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Top Row**

First Question

> I think the answer is 4. In each row, consider the vertical bar of three blue squares moving horizontally in one direction and the single blue square moving in the opposite direction (also it's the only image with three vertical blue squares, like the others)

Second Question

> Number 2. In each row, the third image is the XOR of the other two.

Third Question

> Number 3. In each row if we combine all the images, we get the same total image.

Fourth Question

> Number 4. In each row, the third image is the first image either rotated or diminished (dependent on the second image), in the last row it's both.

**Bottom Row**

First Question

> Number 2. In each row, imagine one of the squares moving diagonally up and to the left and the other up and to the right (where the image wraps around like a torus)

Second Question (three possible answers, both provided in the comments)

> **Prince DeepThinker:** Number 3. In each row, if you overlap the three images, you obtain an image which has exactly four blue squares which, if you colour the underlying grid like a chessboard, are all on white squares or all on black squares.
>  **Matias Stachowski:** Number 5. Both tiles move down and to the left with the exception of when they meet the left edge where they also move one square up (effectively just move left if they are at the left edge and the image wraps around).
>  **SpiritFryer** has given a perhaps cleaner explanation of the same idea. That is, in each row, "each square moves 2 slots forward (wrapping to the start of the next row)"

Third Question (three possible answers with sensible reasoning)

> Number 3. In each row, the third image is just the first image rotated 90 degrees clockwise.
>  **PrinceDeepthinker:** Number 1. Each row has one image with three blue squares and two images with four blue squares.
>  **Matias Stachowski** has given a nice visualisation of each row: Each row has a turning line and an independent dot. The lines turn 45 degrees counter clockwise, and the individual dot has a pattern following the lines. The conclusion is that the answer could be 1,3 or 6 depending on how one visualises it. I see this leading to 3 but Matias has given convincing reasoning how one could also conclude 6 as the answer.

Fourth Question (solved by PrinceDeepthinker)

> Number 3. In each row, the third image represents the squares which have not been coloured in the first two images.

Comment: Hexomino for question first top I think it is 4 because the logic is that if you overlap of the tiles from each row, you get a complete blue square. The bottom second question is 3 because if they all overlap per row you will generate only 4 blue squares. The bottom third is 1 because each row has a tile with 3 blue squares and 2 with 4. The last one on the bottom is 3 for the same reason as the first top.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker Sorry, the question was updated with two extra images since I last looked. I think your answers are correct for the new images. I will leave my logic for top 1 as it is because it also explains the position of the lone square. I'm not sure if I agree with bottom 3 but will edit to present both versions.

Comment: Q6: (bottom #2)
I think It's answer 5. Consider the rows individually. Each tile moves down+left, but with an exception on the left edge where they will also move 1 up. I think it's simpler and more obvious than the chess solution

Comment: @MatiasStachowski That also seems reasonable, will edit in.

Comment: That is annoying that there are multiple legitimate solutions.

Comment: For q7 (bottom #3):
Consider the rows individually. Each row has a turning line and an independent dot. The lines turn 45 degrees counter clockwise, and the individual dot has a pattern following the lines.
In the first row, the individual dot goes through the line in the middle.
In the second row, the dot also goes through the line in the middle.
In the third row, following the line logic, it can either be answer 1, 3 or 6.

The only logical explanation i could find is 6. 
According to: https://i.imgur.com/Egjge05.png 
First row is the unturned lines. Second row is after the turning.

Comment: @MatiasStachowski Actually, you've more convinced me that it is 3 because I see the independent dot as moving through a right angle while the line turns

Comment: @hexomino can you draw a quick diagram with the unturned and the turned lines? I don't see that right angle pattern

Comment: @MatiasStachowski I think the lines are the same as yours. For the independent dot -  first row, it goes bottom right, middle, bottom left. Second row goes middle left, top left, top middle. Third row goes middle left, top left,... which I think should be completed by top middle.

Comment: Sounds reasonable as well :)

Comment: @MatiasStachowski I partially understood why the solution was 3, except what happens when the square reaches the left.

Comment: @gmn_1450 for which question?

Comment: @MatiasStachowski bottom #2

Comment: @gmn_1450 yes, when they get to the left edge, they just shift around to the right edge and go one up.Essentially they just go to the right edge without moving down

Comment: For question 6, each square moves 2 slots forward (wrapping to the start of the next row).

Comment: @SpiritFryer yes, I think this is another (perhaps simpler) way of expressing Matias Stachowski's solution, will edit in.